# How can I define 2 classes in one var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with define a second class in one Var

Here is the Code: http://jsfiddle.net/2DuQc/

How can I make work this fine?

It's written in JQuery!

```
var animateEye = $('.rightEye, .leftEye');
```

doesnt work!

Comment: if you apply `var animateEye = $('.rightEye, .leftEye'); ` in single variable then you have to change the offset for one of the eye, and i think that is left one.

Comment: Yes I know, but I will that 2 eyes are movable with this one function.. I will not write an new one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your code won't work because you are overwriting your variabile with only one selector `.leftEye` so the `.rightEye` will not have nothing attached to it.

You can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) than loop through the result using jQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and apply yuor current code.

Use the same class as inner element and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) it as a children of the current element.

Code:

```
$('.rightEye, .leftEye').each(function () {
    var animateEye = $(this);
    var eyes = animateEye.find(".Eye");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/rU9E2/

Answer (score 3):

```
var animateEye = $('.rightEye, .leftEye');
```

This will give you an **array** of items, so when you call, say, `animateEye.offset()`, which one is it supposed to choose? It'll bomb out.

Your current code:

```
var animateEye = $('.rightEye');
var  eyes = $(".Eye");
var animateEye = $('.leftEye');
```

This will obviously always use `.leftEye`.

My suggestion? Loop through rightEye and leftEye like so:

```
var eyes = $('.rightEye, .leftEye');
for(var i = 0; i < eyes.length; i++) {
    var animateEye = eyes[i];
}
```